# Defining a variable outside of a function in vim

Tags: vimrc

I would like to use a default argument that is defined outside of the function, for example:

```
let DEFAULT_FUNCTION_NAME = 'Toggle3'
func Run(function_name=DEFAULT_FUNCTION_NAME)
    echom function_name
endfunc
```

However, I get an error stating:

> E121: Undefined variable: DEFAULT_FUNCTION_NAME

What would be the possible way to 'scope this' so that I can do something like the above?

Answer (score 1):

Be explicit with the scope: declare it with a given scope

```
let s:var = ...
```

And then use `s:var` (or another scope). Note that `s:` in particular may not work since the default arguments are evaluated at call time!

---

Edit: recent vim supports default function arguments, but I’ll leave this for older versions.

There are a couple of ways I can think of to handle defaults:

1. Pass a “special value” to represent not supplied, and fall back to the default
2. (The approach I see more often) document the use of a particular global variable, and use `let var = get(g:, 'globalvar', default)` to get the value or default for use.

Comment: thanks for this. Though with my vim, I think it supports default args: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/42ae78cfff171fbd7412306083fe200245d7a7a6. I'm just having trouble passing a variable for a default arg, if that's possible.

Comment: Whoa! I missed that!

Comment: Latest Vim versions do support default args. But Neovim still doesn't. IMO, it's better to avoid them for now.